# How do I get the Icon for a shortcut/link in Java?

Tags: java, file, filesystems, icons, system

How do I get the icon for a shortcut/link in Java? I have tried the code below, and it works for files and directories, but not for shortcut/links.

```
Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon( File );
```

Comment: Perhaps it only works for real files. Can you use FileSystemView's getLinkLocation and isLink in order to get the target of the shortcut and then do the same behavior on the file that the shortcut points to?

Comment: @Atmas I'm not sure what do you mean by same behaviour. Do you mean create a shortcut for it in Java? I looked into creating symbolic and hard links, but I am getting I/O issues. It may work if I run in admin, I haven't tried, but this is less ideal.